# How to auto fill date field when editing a text field jquery datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to know how to auto fill date field when text field editing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({     
         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
         maxDate :'0'
    });
});
```

this is my jquery datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setDate property of datepicker to set default date:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('date').value = Date();
   </script>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your comment my input textbox is this <input type="number"
    id="qty_rec<?php echo $num; ?>"